# How to count the number of variables that only occur once in a dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x

For example, in a dataframe column, 1 exists 3 times, 2 exists 1 time, and 3 exists 1 time. So, 2 and 3 are the integers that exists only one time, so the number I want to count is two. How can I make a code for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please keep in mind that stackoverflow is not a code writting service and you should always add what you have tried by yourself. Are you talking about pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `value_counts()`, `eq()`, and `sum()`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"numbers": [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]})
df
#    numbers
# 0        1
# 1        1
# 2        1
# 3        2
# 4        3
num_times = df.numbers.value_counts()
num_times
# 1    3
# 3    1
# 2    1
# Name: numbers, dtype: int64
num_times.eq(1).sum()
# 2
```

Comment: You're new here, but if this answers your question, then you should accept it by clicking the checkmark below the voting UI on the left of the answer.